# Perl here doc: how to add HTML

Tags: perl, heredoc

I'm quite new in Perl. I'm using here document to print out something in our UI.
I could not find a way to add HTML code in here document.

```
my $str = <<"EOF";
<h1>Something</h1>
EOF
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This code should just work... What is the problem that you are having with it?

Comment: @collapsar: Please don't recommend unquoted heredoc delimiters. Using single or double quotes makes it clear to your maintenance programmer (which might well be you in three months time) whether or not variables will be interpolated in the string.

Comment: @SteveS: This code works. Or, at least, you will have HTML in `$str`. The problem is probably in how that string is then displayed. And we can't help solve that problem until you show us that part of the code.

Comment: @DaveCross Thank you for the advice, deleting the comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the UI framework did not interpret the embedded HTML, thus like @DaveCross and you guys said, the embedded HTML should work.